# PHP - error_reporting doesn't work

Tags: php

My webhosting provider doesn't offer the option to enable error reporting.
So tried it with error_reporting(E_ALL); But this also doesn't work.
I tried the following script:

```
 <?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 echo $test;
 ?>
```

If I read the manual correctly, then this should generate an error notice. But this also doesn't work. Did I make something wrong or is the only solution to get a new webhosting provider?

Comment: Set it in your PHP.ini #display_error must be on

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`error_reporting` is just telling PHP how verbose the error reporting should be, but you also need to tell it to actually display errors out to the browser by setting

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Comment: still not enough

Answer (score 5):

You probably want to do something with the triggered error, such as logging it:

```
ini_set('error_log', '/path/to/php-error.log');
```

... and/or displaying it:

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

Please find additional documentation at [Error Handling](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/book.errorfunc.php) and [Runtime Configuration](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php).

---

Addendum: this directive used to be documented as boolean but it's no longer the case. Also, since both the [display_errors](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) directive and [ini_set()](https://php.net/ini_set)'s second argument are of `string` type, when using [strict types](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.declare.php) you won't be able to pass a boolean:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: ini_set() expects parameter 2 to be string, bool given

Thus you'll need to pass a string that evals to true such as `'true'` or `'1'`.

Answer (score 2):

You also need:

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
```

Answer (score 2):

If its a shared hosting then for security reasons, they may disable error reporting, still they should be able to provide error log for your particular domain, try talking to them if they don't want to show it inline - get access go log file or maybe some adminpanel that can read it securely.