# Read log file in /var/log with php

Tags: php, logging

how to make php can read log file in /var/log/....

I tried this code but not work

```
<?php
    $file = "/var/log/smsd.log"; //gammu's sms log
    $data = file($file);

    $end = count($data);
    $first = $end-10;

    $number = range($first,$end);

    foreach($number as $n) {
        $log_data .= $data[$n]."\n";
    }

    echo $log_data;
?>
```

But, It is work if i try to read file in same folder with this script.

Comment: "Does not work" is not an error message, nor a problem description.

Comment: You should firstly try `var_dump(is_readable($file));`

Comment: `gammu's sms log`, are you trying to read someone else's sms pattern? :o

Comment: @PeeHaa I don't know.. I just confused. Is file() can't read system file or not?

Comment: @Teneff no result there. just blank..

Comment: @SiGanteng no. I just try to show gammu's log file to web interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"but not work" is not an error message. Check you're configuration [has error reporting enabled.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10103307/php-error-reporting-doesnt-work).

Most likely it's a permissions issue. How you fix this depends on your operating system and how you manage your log files (but you'll probably find the answers in the [chmod](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/chmod/) and [logrorate](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate) man pages).

BTW, your code will also fall over if it has to read very large files. Consider using

```
<pre><?php
   passthru('tail -10 /var/log/smsd.log');
?></pre>
```

Comment: I don't know where is my fault.. I use same as your code but not with passthru. I use exec. And the web is not getting stop from loading.