# error_reporting(E_ALL) does not produce an error

Tags: php

This is my PHP script -

```
<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  echo('catch this -> ' ;. $thisdoesnotexist);
?>
```

Which obviously should show something if it were to be executed.

All I see is an empty page. Why is `error_reporting(E_ALL)` not working?

```
<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", "1");
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  echo('catch this -> ' ;. $thisdoesnotexist);
?>
```

Does not help either. All I get is an empty page.

I've been to `php.ini` and set `display_errors = On` and `display_startup_errors = On`. Nothing happens.

Comment: How is `display_errors` setup?

Comment: check display_errors setting

Comment: Does not help, as I've reflected in my question edit.

Comment: You can check your syntax first by running `php -l <file>`

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP - error\_reporting doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10103307/php-error-reporting-doesnt-work)

Comment: Is "`;.`" an intentional error?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Your file has a syntax error, so your file was not interpreted, so settings were not changed and you have a blank page.

You can separate your file in two:

#### File *index.php*

```
<?php
    ini_set("display_errors", "1");
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    include 'error.php';
```

#### File *error.php*

```
<?
    echo('catch this -> ' ;. $thisdoesnotexist);
```

Comment: This one works. The index.php shows the error. But no matter what I do, error.php remains a big empty page.

Answer (score 10):

That error is a *parse error*. The *parser* is throwing it while going through the code, trying to understand it. **No code is being executed yet in the parsing stage.** Because of that it hasn't yet executed the `error_reporting` line, therefore the error reporting settings aren't changed yet.

You cannot change error reporting settings (or really, do *anything*) in a file with syntax errors.

Answer (score 10):

In your php.ini file check for `display_errors`. I think it is off.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```

Comment: I just set both of them to On. No changes.

Comment: you wont inline, they need to be set in the php ini file

Answer (score 4):

In your *php.ini* file check for *display_errors*. If it is off, then make it on as below:

```
display_errors = On
```

It should display warnings/notices/errors.

Please read *[error_reporting int](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting)*.

Comment: What does *"it"* refer to in *"It should display warnings/notices/errors."*? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16933673/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score 2):

You can try to put this in your *php.ini*:

```
ini_set("display_errors", "1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

In *php.ini* file also you can set `error_reporting();`.

Comment: If it is a parse error, how would this help? What system did you test this on (for the question at hand)? What was the result?

Answer (score 0):

Turn on display errors in your ini file:

*[display_errors string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors)*

Answer (score 0):

Just do the following:

1. Check `phpinfo();`. Check if `display_errors` is on or off
2. If it is `On`, just add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` in your primary index file.
3. If it is `Off`, just add it in your primary index file

   `ini_set("display_errors", "1"); // This is the instant setup for individual applications`
   `error_reporting(E_ALL);`
4. then check `phpinfo();`. Check `display_errors`. Now it is `on`, which is only for this application
5. then create any code error for testing and reload the page

Hurray! Now you can see the errors in your console. If the errors are not displaying in your console and the page loading failed with a red alert in network, don't worry.

Check if you have enabled `modsecurity` and it has any rule checking is written in `SecRule` for PHP. Remove that secrule or disable the `modsecurity` for your development period.

Comment: Where is "modsecurity" located? What file? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67837148/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: If it is a parse error, how would this help? What system did you test this on (for the question at hand)? What was the result?

Comment: Modsecurity is the nginx/apache module and we need to install it seperately and I tested this codes on debian