# Not getting PHP errors?

Tags: php

For some reason on this particular script, which is a copy of a script I use in a lot of other places, I am not getting any PHP errors.  It simply shows a blank page, and It took me a long long time to hunt down a missing semi-colon this morning.  Why arn't errors showing up?

my PHP.INI for this sub-domain:

```
display_errors = On
short_open_tag = On
memory_limit = 32M
date.timezone = Europe/Paris
```

The code at the top of the page:

```
session_start();

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

The Sub Domain is set to run PHP as an `Apache Module` Which is the same as every other domain I use.

So I am not sure why I am not getting errors displayed.  Can anyone tell me?

**EDIT:**
This is solved, because the errors I was producing were on the page where I had got the lines:
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', '1');
written.  When I put the error on to a seperate page and included it, I could see the error fine.

I guess that's why they use bootstrapping!

Comment: check the error log report, on your hosting control panel.

Comment: possible duplicate of [error\_reporting(E\_ALL) does not produce error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16933606/error-reportinge-all-does-not-produce-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to change this lines to get more information from php:

```
 ; The display of errors which occur during PHP's startup sequence are handled
 ; separately from display_errors. PHP's default behavior is to suppress those
 ; errors from clients. Turning the display of startup errors on can be useful in
 ; debugging configuration problems. But, it's strongly recommended that you
 ; leave this setting off on production servers.

 display_startup_errors = On

 ; When PHP displays or logs an error, it has the capability of formatting the
 ; error message as HTML for easier reading. This directive controls whether
 ; the error message is formatted as HTML or not.
 ; Note: This directive is hardcoded to Off for the CLI SAPI

 html_errors = On
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set `error_reporting` to E_ALL in the `php.ini` as well: when a parse error occurs (such as a missing semicolon), your `error_reporting(E_ALL)` won't be used.

Answer (score 0):

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
```