# php error_reporting() method in the 5.6.3 version

Tags: php, error-reporting

In the following example:

```
<?php
 // this code is written to test error reporting function in runtime
error_reporting(0);
echo $var = 'hex'  // I have made this mistake here by my will but error reporting message still pops up.
$name = 'rex';
?>
```

I wanted to turn off the error reporting in php at runtime. I used the statement `error_reporting(0);` 
but it dosen't work for my version, it tried the solution proposed by the following question [php error reporint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16933606/error-reportinge-all-does-not-produce-error) but it doesen't work. I think another version is used here. 
My php version is ***php 5.6.3***. I have checked the [php doumentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) for a soltion but I couldn't find an answer. 
How can I solve this ?

Comment: @symcbean I  am saying to you that the code still shows the error message and I am asking the reason of this. Did you read the question well? Normally it mustnt show but it is still showing it in my browser.

Comment: @isymcbean is it impossible to disable it from inside a php file ?

Comment: @pentanol It is when the file can't be even executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A semicolon is missing at the end of the second line of code

```
echo $var = 'hex'
```

This is the cause of the error and this is a compile error, not a runtime error. Because it cannot be compiled successfully, the script is not started at all. There is no runtime, the script never ran.

There is no way to suppress compile errors. Their purpose is to show the programmer that the script cannot be compiled and why.

Comment: I know the semi colon is missing. It is me who did this. I am saying why error_reportong(0); instruction doesen't turn off error reporting. Read the question well please.

Comment: I read your question, you did not read my answer. The instruction `error_reporting(0);` did not run. Your script was not interpreted at all. It failed on the compilation phase. The PHP script is compiled before being interpreted. The compilation checks its syntax and produces a "compiled" form of the program. This is a binary form that is interpreted by the interpreter; you can think of it as an executable program. Because the compilation failed, no binary form was produced and your script was never executed.

Comment: You have a wrong understanding of how the PHP interpreter works. It doesn't read and execute the script one line after the other. It reads the entire file, checks its syntax and turns it into its internally binary format **if it does not have any syntax errors**. Then it starts interpreting it. Your script has syntax errors (a missing semicolon), this is why the compilation fails, no binary format is produced and the interpreter does not have any code to interpret; i.e. the script does not run at all; not even the call to `error_reporting()`.

Comment: you mean that error_reporting() is just related to runtime errors not syntax errors.

Comment: Exactly. And it have to be executed to have any effect. Put an `echo("My script is running");` before `error_reporting();` to check yourself that your script is not executed.

Comment: I changed my code, it is working fine. I opened the php.ini file and error reporting wasnt set to zero as i wanted. Is there any dynamic way to change the content on php.ini ? If it is not possible what to do in case of public servers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68969/discussion-between-axiac-and-pentanol).

Answer (score 1):

You have a compile error; The comments on the error_reporting suggest that compile time errors may not be controllable through run time directives.

This would NOT cause any error to appear

```
error_reporting(0);
echo $var = 'hex';
$name = 'rex';
echo $A;
```

This would cause an error to appear

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo $var = 'hex';
$name = 'rex';
echo $A;
```

This would also cause an error to appear

```
error_reporting(0);
echo $var = 'hex'
$name = 'rex';
echo $A;
```

Comment: I am not trying to correct the error. I am trying to see if the error_reporting(0); turns of the error reporting in the runtime. But it doesent turn it of in my php version. I am seeking how to turn it off.